# NSString to int loses precision

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, int

I have a text string that represents a certain value without floating point number:

```
NSString *value1 = @"20141014135017";
NSString *value2 = @"20141014131024";

int one = [value1 intValue];
int two = [value2 intValue];
```

Why the result of **one** and **two** is only **2147483647**? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`int` values can only support a limited number of bits. You should use `float` or `double`.
Here is a more comprehensive text on integers [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform, but on a 32-bit platform the limit of `int` is +/- 2 billion (−2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 to be precise).

Use `long` instead:

```
long one = [value1 longValue];
long two = [value2 longValue];
```